# Does compareTo work with double type?

Tags: java, double, compareto

I need to make a program that uses compareTo, but I'm running into issues with it.

```
double sides1 = 1.0;
double sides2 = 1.3;
int compared = sides1.compareTo(sides2);
```

I always run into an error that says

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call methods on primitive values such as `double`s.  But you can call [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-), which will compare two primitive `double`s for you.

```
int compared = Double.compare(sides1, sides2);
```

You can also compare primitive `double` values directly with the comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

A primitive type is not a Java Object and so the method compareTo does not exist.  Use the Java Object Double and not the primitive type:

```
Double sides1 = Double.valueOf(1.0);
Double sides2 = Double.valueOf(1.3);
int compared = sides1.compareTo(sides2);
```

Edit - do not take from that that all Java Objects have the compareTo(..) method. The compareTo(..) is part of the Comparable Interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a primitive type, not a class : it has not method. You should be using `Double` instead... and reviewing the basics in Java. Not to be offensive, but the thing is that you need the basics to efficiently program.

PS : you can also use the static method `Double.compare`